# How to use extended monitor with different image on each monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, extended-desktop

How can I use extended monitor set of two HP- EM869A [has Two connectors: one 15-pin mini D-sub analog VGA and one DVI-D (VGA analog or digital)] with my Gateway DX4840-37. I have one vga and one HDMI port on back panel. I do not want duplicate image on both monitors I want to run different application display separately on each monitors.
What is the inexpenssive option with  reasonably good quality of display

Comment: Likely yes, but it depends on your Operating system. What Operating System are you using (please add version/distro/etc) The more info, the better.

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit OS with intel core i5 CPU 650 @3.20Ghz+ 8gab Ram(4gb original+ 4gb additional)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 allows for extending the desktop. That is the two screens appears a one extremely large one. By extending the desktop you can move windows across them. The programs are only shown on the monitor it is dragged to.

more information http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064

I personally use this with VMplayer to virtualize Linux in windows * and display Linux on the second screen

Shourtcut to acces extended diaplay

```
Windows Key+ P
```

Comment: I know how it works, however, I wanted to know only what kind of hardware additionally I may need and how it should be connected. my confusion is different. I learned that VGA Y spliter cable will give me same image on both display. If I will buy DMS 59 output card or DVI output card  and use spliter connector would it be give same image on both monitor or different? is any option using HDMI spliter for this?

Comment: No splitters. Two separate connectors, from among those you have available, i.e. HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc. Then you can even run two different resolutions. In your case, based on your statements, use the HDMI and VGA connectors, one cable from each to one monitor, then set Win7 to extend the desktop rather than clone it.